# Smart sorting that ignores leading zeros and date formats while sorting in PHP

Tags: php

I have a php script that sorts 2 multi-dimensional arrays. Now if i use plain array_multisort it jumbles the 2 arrays for certain rows because both arrays have some tricky elements

eg: a[2][2]='35'
and b[2][2]='0035'

also, a[3][4]='+0.03'
b[3][4]='+.03'

a[4][6]='31-12-2012'
b[4][6]='12/31/2012'

Because of the above tricky element difference sorting of both arrays gives different result. I need them to sort appropriately because my req are to do one-to-match across each row for analysis purposes.

Please suggest how do I go ahead to 'smart' sort these arrays to give same result

i have tried something on the lines of

```
                function sort2dArray($data) {
                    $tmp = array();
                    $lineCount = count($data);
                    foreach ($data as $lineNum => $lineData) {
                        foreach ($lineData as $column => $value) {
                            $tmp[$column][$lineNum] = standardize($value);
                        }
                    }

                    $multiSortArgs = array();
                    foreach ($tmp as $column => $columnData) {
                        array_push($multiSortArgs, $columnData, SORT_ASC);
                    }
                    $multiSortArgs[] = &$data;
                    call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $multiSortArgs);
                    return $data;
                }



                function standardize($value)
                {
                    if(is_numeric($value))
                        $pval= $value + 0;
                    else
                        $pval= $value;

                    return $pval;
                }
```

**UPDATE: o/p from both arrays with ',' as delimiter...only considering the 0035 and 35 case**

```
            BA2063,,,110Y,EFW
            BA2063,,,110Y,EFW
            BA2063,,,110Y,EFW
            BA2063,,,121H,ECD
            BA2063,,,121H,ECD
            BA2063,,,121H,ECD
            BA2063,,,0035,ESW
            BA2063,,,0035,EFW
            BA2063,,,0035,EFW
            BA2063,,,0035,EFW
            BA2063,,,1L9M,EFW






            BA2063,,,1L9M,EFW
            BA2063,,,35,ESW
            BA2063,,,35,EFW
            BA2063,,,35,EFW
            BA2063,,,35,EFW
            BA2063,,,110Y,EFW
            BA2063,,,110Y,EFW
            BA2063,,,110Y,EFW
            BA2063,,,121H,ECD
            BA2063,,,121H,ECD
            BA2063,,,121H,ECD
```

Comment: can you display the result of both array's using var dump so we get a brief idea

Comment: it sounds like your input data source is really low quality. a well managed system shouldn't be giving you data in mixed formats in the first place (particularly not mixed date formats -- that's asking for trouble given the potential ambiguities you can have with dates)

Comment: @SDC agreed but cant really help. I need to find some way to tackle this now..

Comment: well the dates *are* going to be a problem unless you know what formats to expect. `12-31-2012` may be obvious, but what date is `12-03-2012`? and is it the same as `12/03/2012`? Unless you can tell it in advance what the format is, PHP's default guess is those are two different dates.

Comment: @SDC its 12-31-2012, its in mm-dd-yyyy format. Would that affect PHP's sorting. I thought PHP could sort well with dates in different recognized formats

Comment: updated by question above. say, how i can specify the date format to PHP in advance for sorting purposes?

Comment: no, PHP can't sort arbitrary date strings; you have to convert them to either a timestamp integer or DateTime objects before PHP can sort them. But that conversion won't always work well if the format is unknown, particularly when your incoming formats have a mixture of hyphens and slashes as per the question, because without any other clues, PHP will use the slashes or hyphens a clue as to whether the date is in `dd-mm-yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` format. So unless you can do some pre-processing to tidy up the input dates, you are very likely to end up with errors.

Comment: The old saying "Garbage in, garbage out" definitely applies here. It's very hard to write program to produce reliable output when the input is unreliable.

Comment: @SDC should sorting by sha1 hash produce correct result? I am able to get all data type mismatch sorted by taking hash  but would hash of numbers sort properly?

Comment: no it wouldn't. a hash would randomise the sort order even more (in fact, hashes are often used specifically to provide a random sort order). If you want the dates sorted in date order, you need to get them into a consistent, sortable format.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is quite hard to understand as you have multi type datas and multi format dates.
If you have mixed dateFormat, I propose you to filter your array with that kind of function :

```
$authorizedFormats= ['Y-m-d','m/d/Y'];//give all your format, be careful inside the order to avoid abiguity mess

$filterVarOptions =['options'=>function($var)use($authorizedFormats){
             foreach($authorizedFormats as $value){
                  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($value,$var);
                  if($date !==false){
                      return $date;
                  }
             }
           return new DateTime('01/01/70');
         }];
 array_walk($yourMultiDimArray,function($var)use($filterVarOptions){
          foreach($var as &$value)
            $value = filter_var($value,FILTER_CALLBACK,$filterVarOptions);
       });
```

Comment: not at all. if you have got a DateTime object, it is sortable with the default operators.